# How to search on Windows Update History?

Tags: windows-7, windows

If I try to search for a KB Number on Control Panel > Windows Update > View Update History, typing on the upper right corner search box, the search is not performed on the History but on the Control Panel itself.

How to search on completed/failed updates ?

Comment: I've never found a good method for doing this (and I have looked extensively). if you find a good answer, please post it, but my experience is telling me that you can't.

Comment: It seems that it's not really possible to use the search box to find a specific KB update, but using [this](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-print-the-windows-update-history-in-vista/) solution you can export a tab delimited list and then use excel "Find All" search function to see if an update marked as failed was later completed.
@frankthomas

Comment: For installed updates, click 'View installed update' on the Programs and Features control panel. The Search function for KB works there. No infromation about failed updates there though.

Answer (score 7):

Use Powershell to search for installed Windows updates

`Get-Hotfix` retrieves all current installed updates on the machine, use the `-id` switch to specify KB number.

Example:

```
PS C:\Users\User> Get-HotFix -Id kb974322
Get-HotFix : Cannot find the requested hotfix on the 'localhost' computer. Verify the input and run the command again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-HotFix -Id kb974322
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-HotFix], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetHotFixNoEntriesFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHotFixCommand

PS C:\Users\User> Get-HotFix -Id kb3105216

Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------
LP     Security Update  KB3105216     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  11-4-2015 00:00:00


PS C:\Users\User> Get-HotFix -Id kb3105216 | fl


Description         : Security Update
FixComments         :
HotFixID            : KB3105216
InstallDate         :
InstalledBy         : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
InstalledOn         : 11-4-2015 00:00:00
Name                :
ServicePackInEffect :
Status              :
```

Comment: For those who need to know how to run (or install) PowerShell: [Installing Windows PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6)